# Tree Traversal and First Order Functions

Tags: java, generics, tree, traversal, higher-order-functions

Suppose I have a Tree class and a Node class

```
public class Tree{
    private Node root;
    public Tree(Node root){ this.root = root; }
}

public class Node{
    private ArrayList<Node> children;
    private Node parent;
    private String label;
    private String someInfo;
    private int someIntegerInfo;
    private MyObject someObject;   // Where MyObject is from some other class
    ...

    public Node(Node parent, ArrayList<Node> children, String label, String foo, ...){
        this.parent = parent;
        this.children = children;
        this.someInfo = foo;
        ...
    }
}
```

Now suppose I need to do, say, in-order depth-first traversal of these Tree objects to extract information. Maybe I want to do it once to build a string of all the Node labels as they are visited, and another time I want to perform some operation on the int field, etc.

As I'm writing these traversals, I of course notice that I'm writing the same code to do the traversal over an over again, but performing different actions on the nodes or returning different types.

```
public something traverse(Node node, something foo){
    // Do some stuff with foo here
    ...
    for( Node child: node.getChildren() ){
        return child.traverse();
    }
    return foo;
}
```

Is there a way Java to have a function that only does the traversal, but then takes a higher order function as an argument that handles collecting whatever sort of information I'm trying to get? Or is there a better way to do this that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: This is a good scenario where closure is helpful. Java haven't yet provided closure support. So Jiri's answer is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

You may encapsulate an operation into a Java class:

```
public interface NodeOperation {
   void perform(Node node);
}

public void traverse(Node node, NodeOperation op) {
    op.perform(node);
    for(Node child: node.getChildren()) {
        traverse(child, op);
    }
}

//then for performing the operation during the traversal call following code
traverse(node, new NodeOperation() {
   perform(Node node) {
      // do whatever you want
      node.setSomeIntegerInfo(node.getSomeIntegerInfo() * 42);
   }
});
```

In Java 8 there is a better way to do this using the closures.